# Why am I able to create an instance of a generic class in Swift although not all parameters are initialized?

Tags: swift, generics

```
class Element<T> {
    var inhalt: T
    var naechstes: Element<T>?

    init (_ inhalt: T) {
        self.inhalt = inhalt
    }
}

var elem1 = Element ()
```

Why am I able to create an instance of a generic class in swift although not all parameters are initialized?

I wrote this code and I find it strange that it is possible to create an instance of the Element class without parameters. Doesn't the variable "inhalt" need to be initialized because it isn't an optional?

Answer (score 2):

In your case, in

```
var elem1 = Element ()
```

the generic type `T` is inferred to be `Void` (aka `()`), so `elem1`
has the type `Element<()>` and is initialized with an empty argument list.

This works because `T` is an arbitrary type in your class definition.
If you restrict it to some protocol

```
 class Element<T : SomeProtocol > { ... }
```

then you can only instantiate it with types adopting that protocol.
The protocol should describe the properties and methods which 
`T` is expected to have.

Comment: how can you change this behaviour??

Comment: @IneedHelpFromYou: Why do you want to change it, `Void` is a valid type. – On the other hand, if you need `T` to have certain "properties" then you should restrict the generic definition to a protocol which describes what you need: `class Element<T : SomeProtocol > { ... }`.